# SSIS - SQL Server Integration Services

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm moving an application from an Access database to a SQL Server database.

The current Access database contains 5 'linked' Excel files (reports that come from SAP) which are refreshed daily by overwriting each file with the new SAP report.  In this way, through a bunch of transformation/queries, the data ends up in the appropriate table in the way we want to store the data.

Is a setup similar to this possible using SSIS?  I've watched tutorials about uploading Excel files into a table, but essentially I need to do this:

SAP Export > Save (overwrite) to Network File > MS Access link exists and new data is transformed through many 'stored procedures (action queries)' > Data moved to appropriate table.

Appreciate any YouTube/Google/Links/Reading about doing this in SSIS.  Regards!

Comment: There are several approaches to meeting your objective, but more information is first needed before proceeding.  1) Do the names of each of the five Excel files differ from one day to the next (e.g., file name includes a date stamp)?  2) Do all five Excel files share the same layout (same worksheet name, same columns with the same headers and so forth)?  First importing the data from these files into staging tables that are first truncated before loading is easily done in SSIS.  From the staging tables you can clean things up and then move to a final destination.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Both to load from excel or from MS Access